# Syntax error in vb

Tags: vb.net

```vb
' Load data for the ViewModel Items
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)
    Using (StudentContext c = New StudentContext(StudentContext.ConnectionString))
        c.CreateIfNotExists()
        c.LogDebug = True
        MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = c.Students.ToList()
    End Using
End Sub
```

I have error  `')' expects and in line 3 on "c"`. How to handle this? Thanks

Comment: You're mixing VB .NET syntax and C#. Your question is tagged C#, but the syntax is VB .NET

Comment: This is definitely not C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using C# syntax in VB .NET.

Try

```
Using c as StudentContext = New StudentContext(StudentContext.ConnectionString)
```